# Create new column that counts each string match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, multiple-columns

I aim to create a new column based on multiple string matches. This new column will return a 1 number for every match on the event column.

```
        Date        Event
0 2022-11-01        Breakfast
1 2022-11-01        Breakfast
2 2022-11-01        Lunch
3 2022-11-02        Breakfast
4 2022-11-02        Lunch
```

After

```
        Date        Event        Breakfast        Lunch
0 2022-11-01        Breakfast        1            null
1 2022-11-01        Breakfast        1            null
2 2022-11-01        Lunch            null         1
3 2022-11-02        Breakfast        1            null
4 2022-11-02        Lunch            null         1
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? What have you tried, and where are you stuck? For example, do you know how to use `Series.str.count()`? Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Count occurrences of each of certain words in pandas dataframe](/q/17573814/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.get_dummies` for the task:

```py
out = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['Event'])], axis=1)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
         Date      Event  Breakfast  Lunch
0  2022-11-01  Breakfast          1      0
1  2022-11-01  Breakfast          1      0
2  2022-11-01      Lunch          0      1
3  2022-11-02  Breakfast          1      0
4  2022-11-02      Lunch          0      1
```

---

If you want `None` instead `0`:

```py
out = out.replace({0: None})
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
         Date      Event Breakfast Lunch
0  2022-11-01  Breakfast         1  None
1  2022-11-01  Breakfast         1  None
2  2022-11-01      Lunch      None     1
3  2022-11-02  Breakfast         1  None
4  2022-11-02      Lunch      None     1
```

Comment: IMO `join` is easier than `concat` (`df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Event']))`) ;)

Comment: I used join as @mozway suggested and found this gave me what I needed. Thanks both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function as well:

```
df['Breakfast'] = df.Event.map({'Breakfast': 1})
df['Lunch'] = df.Event.map({'Lunch': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is as easy as a trick.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["2022-11-01", "Breakfast"],
                  ["2022-11-01", "Breakfast"],
                  ["2022-11-01", "Lunch"],
                  ["2022-11-02", "Breakfast"],
                  ["2022-11-02", "Lunch"]], columns=["date", "event"])
```

###### Solution

```
df["temp"] = df["event"]
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix="", prefix_sep="", columns=["temp"])
```

###### Output

```
    date        event       Breakfast   Lunch
0   2022-11-01  Breakfast   1           0
1   2022-11-01  Breakfast   1           0
2   2022-11-01  Lunch       0           1
3   2022-11-02  Breakfast   1           0
4   2022-11-02  Lunch       0           1
```